# Create a webhook (node.js)

Tags: node.js, api, chatbot, ngrok

I was asked to develop a demo RCS chatbot so I copied [this node.js demo from github](https://github.com/pvangool/rcs-maap-bot/blob/develop/example/echo-express.js) which listens on `localhost:300`. I now need to provide a permanent webhook for it.

I found something called `ngrok` which automatically creates a webhook URL that points to my pc on port 3000 but it only lasts for 8 hours!

Is there a way to create a permanent webhook URL?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: This isn't an RCS (revision control system) question, so i've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up for a `ngrok` account, whether free or paid one, you will have a tunnel and a webhook URL that has **no time** limit.

Only `ngrok` sessions that are started without an auth token have a time limit.